# Delimiter as text column format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem using the delimiter "^" in splitting text into columns. Can someone help me?

[image]

the top will have the same output format with the bottom format after importing multiple .txt files.

Here's the Excel VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim oFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim LoopFolderPath As String
Dim oFileSystem As FileSystemObject
Dim oLoopFolder As Folder
Dim oFilePath As File
Dim oFile As TextStream
Dim RowN As Long
Dim ColN As Long
Dim iAnswer As Integer
On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

Set oFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

RowN = 1
ColN = 1

With oFileDialog
If .Show Then
    ActiveSheet.Columns(ColN).Cells.Clear

    LoopFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    Set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oLoopFolder = oFileSystem.GetFolder(LoopFolderPath)

    For Each oFilePath In oLoopFolder.Files
        Set oFile = oFileSystem.OpenTextFile(oFilePath)

        With oFile

            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowN, ColN).Value = .ReadLine
                ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").TextToColumns _
                    Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Other:=True, OtherChar:="^"
                ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                LoopFolderPath = Space(1)
                RowN = RowN + 1
            Loop

            .Close
        End With
    Next oFilePath
End If
iAnswer = MsgBox("Your Textfiles have been Inputted.", vbInformation)

End With

EXIT_SUB:
Set oFilePath = Nothing
Set oLoopFolder = Nothing
Set oFileSystem = Nothing
Set oFileDialog = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:

    Err.Clear
    GoTo EXIT_SUB

End Sub
```

Comment: the code is already linked.

Comment: The questions are intended to last in order to help others in the future. This linked code may not work in the future, as is handled by external people and external company. Add the code here, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and you will reduce your possibilities of downvotes or closed question. Better questions create better answers.

Comment: What's the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `TextToColumns` on the entire column after each inserted line may cause values to be overwritten. Call `TextToColumns` and `AutoFit` only once after all values have been inserted.

```
With oFile
  Do Until .AtEndOfStream
    ActiveSheet.Cells(RowN, ColN).Value = .ReadLine
    LoopFolderPath = Space(1)
    RowN = RowN + 1
  Loop
  .Close
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1") _
  , DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Other:=True _
  , OtherChar:="^"
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
```

To organize the data in columns rather than rows, I'd suggest to insert the data as rows and then copy them to a new sheet using the `Transpose` operation:

```
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
Sheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: the problem hasn't been solved. The code only did a row delimiter split rather than a column delimiter split. . . :(

Comment: the output was still the same . . .

Comment: The output is still the same which was a row delimiter split. The output must be a column delimiter split ( . . . <a link> https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_eArBbGfxv4RTl0NTU3b01oX0U/edit?usp=sharing !

Comment: Well, you still neglected to describe what the actual problem is. My answer was merely pointing out one potential issue I saw in your code. I'm not sure what you mean by "column delimiter split". Do you want the fields of each line in one column rather than in one row?

Comment: @jinomar25 You should have explained that in your question. See updated answer.